# AsyncSelect react-select multi with active options in menu

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a simple react app with [react-select Async select](https://react-select.com/async):

```
 const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  const loadOptions = async (inputValue, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback([
        { value: 'apple', label: 'Apple' },
        { value: 'amazon', label: 'Amazon' },
        { value: 'Microsoft', label: 'Microsoft' },
        { value: 'Winter', label: 'Winter' },
        { value: 'Autumn', label: 'Autumn' },
        { value: 'Summer', label: 'Summer' },
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  };


    <div>
      <AsyncSelect
        isMulti
        name="select"
        isClearable
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
      />
    </div>
```

**Question:**
How can I do a multi select, but with a selection of multiple options in the list (add check)?
How to display the total number of selected options in a field?

p.s:
It should look like this:

[image]